# One liner for list unnesting can't take a function within?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to filter the list below by keeping only strings while keeping the structure (double lists), I can do so with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

Mah_list = [[1170, 'Ars antica', 'Ars nova', 'Ars subtilior'], [1890, 'Impressionism', 'Expressionism']]

for sublst in Mah_list:
  for el in sublst:
    if type(el) != str:
      sublst.remove(el)

print(Mah_list)
```

Why is the following one-liner not working ?

```
Filtered_list = [sublst.remove(x) for sublst in Mah_list for x in sublst if type(x) != str]
print(Filtered_list)
```

Thank you !

Comment: The `remove` method acts in-place and returns `None`.  It does not return the modified list.

Comment: I tried it with .del() & .pop() since they require indexes but in vain

Comment: *don't use list comprehensions for side effects*

Comment: Note, your original algorithm doesn't work in the general case

Comment: Also don't remove / add to a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension:

```py
Mah_list = [
    [1170, "Ars antica", "Ars nova", "Ars subtilior"],
    [1890, "Impressionism", "Expressionism"],
]

Mah_list = [[v for v in subl if isinstance(v, str)] for subl in Mah_list]
print(Mah_list)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ["Ars antica", "Ars nova", "Ars subtilior"],
    ["Impressionism", "Expressionism"],
]
```

Comment: All I lacked was the syntax ... I tried something like this, thanks buddy